# List of abbreviations using setlist and enumitem package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem

I am writing a list of abbreviations. This is the format that I use.

[image]

So I use this configuration

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
```

Where the way I write abbreviation is: `\item[FPGA]:Field Programmable Gate Array`

The problem is when the explanation is more than one line then it looks like this.

[image]

The format should be like this:
[image]

The first letter of the new line should be aligned with the first line

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using semilcolons to begin with? They're not needed.

Comment: I also think it is not necessary. But, It is the writing format of the University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `:` to be part of the label itself. I would use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{#1\hfill:}
\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=myleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\begin{document}
\begin{abbrv}
\item[FPGA]Field programmable gate array with some extra words to show how it wraps.
\end{abbrv}
\end{document}
```

Although I tend to agree with Mico's comment that the colons aren't really necessary anyway.

[image: output of code]

Comment: That works for me.